# awk to sort by field in output

Tags: awk

I have an `awk` that creates the file.txt below:

```
awk '{if((NR>1)&&($4!=last)){printf("%s\t%f\t%s\n", last,  total/len,pg);total=$7;len=1;}else{total+=$7;len+=1};pg=$5;last=$4;}END{printf("%s\t%f\t%s\n",  last, total/len,pg)}' a.bam > file.txt | awk '{if($2>=1000.00)print;}' file.txt > sort.txt
```

I can not figure out if the calculated value in $2 is less than or equal to 100 then that line the font changed to red, then the entire file is sort in ascending order by $2 Is this possible?  Thank you :).

**file.txt**

```
chr1:40539722-40539865    227.776224    PPT1
chr1:40542503-40542595    109.706522    PPT1
chr1:40544221-40544340    61.596639    PPT1
```

Comment: 1. I don't see a source of your data. A basic awk program will look like `awk '{print $0}' inputfile [morethan 1 inputfile is possible] > outputfile`. You haven't specified an inputfile. AND you can't use the same name for both files as that will wipe out your data. (Always work with a backup). 2. What do you mean 'changed to red'. Awk is strictly a text processor. You could have it generate html tags to make red text on a web page, OR you can use ansi-escape sequences to make the text red on the command line. Get these 2 things solved (edit your question!) . Then deal with the sort. Good luck

Comment: The `awk` uses an input a.bam to create the file.txt.  I would then like to use file.txt to further process the data by maybe just simply sorting by $2 (smallest to largest) and store the output as sort.txt.  So in the example line 3 would be on top, followed by line 2, then line 3.  Thank you :).  I will edit post 1 to try and reflect these.

Comment: only in very special cases shoul you use `awk` to sort data. (this is not one of those cases). Given your need to sort on $2, try `sort -k2n file.txt > sort.txt`.

Comment: questions in the form of 1.  sample data should include samples for each case of your problem and a few lines of data that wouldn't be affected (if appropriate), 2.  required output from that data, 3.code I am using, 4.current output 5  any error messages (don't use `2>/dev/null`). 6. my thoughts will have much high likelyhood of attracting help from readers here. Consider updating your question to this standard. Good luck!